# Dynotopo warning “Vertex Data Detected”

Tags: sculpting, vertex-groups, dynamic-topology

I am doing an Anime female model for my animations I am not a beginner, but still finding my way around Blender.
It seems like every object I use that is poly does not work I use the subdivision modifier. So there is plenty of polygons to sculpt. Then go to sculpt then get the Vertex data warning. I get spikes in my objects which is annoying.

I tried sculpting the character but I like building the character the way I want then start sculpting.
I have been having these issues for months.

I would really appreciate the help. Thank you

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to blender have version 2.90...
Maybe you can try this.
**Click on the "Object Data Properties" tab (the green triangle, third last  on the right), then unfold "UV Maps" and click the minus symbol on the right.**
I don't know what will be the effect but I'm sure it'll not complain you...
Hope it will help.      Thank you!