# How do you keep Dyntopo from turning itself off and get rid of the vertex data warning?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, sculpting

I'm new to blender and I'm trying to mess around with the sculpting tools. I noticed occasionally the dyntopo option turns itself off and I have to pass a warning every time I want to re-enable it. How do I keep dyntopo from turning itself off and suppress the vertex data warning altogether?

Answer (score 2):

Found a soultion here: [Dynotopo warning “Vertex Data Detected”](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195167/dynotopo-warning-vertex-data-detected)

> Click on the "Object Data Properties" tab (the green triangle, third
> last on the right), then unfold "UV Maps" and click the minus symbol
> on the right.

Comment: FWIW the main developer in charge of sculpt tools has said publicly that you should only use Dyntopo for very specific use-cases like the Snake Hook tool, and then immediately turn it off, primarily relying on the Multires or Remesh options to get you mesh res where you need it. Apparently the performance with Dyntopo is a complete joke compared to just using the other two options.